# Read from file to dictionary as floats instead of strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, file-io, dictionary

I'm loading and extracting data from python, which I want to be stored in a dictionary.

I'm using csv to write read the data and externally it is just stored as to comma-separated columns. This works great, but when the data is initially read it (obviously) is read as string.
I can convert it to a dictionary with both keys and values as floats using two lines of code, but my question whether I can load the data directly as floats into a dictionary.

My original code was:

```
reader = csv.reader(open('testdict.csv','rb'))
dict_read = dict((x,y) for (x,y) in reader)
```

Which I have changed to:

```
reader = csv.reader(open('testdict.csv','rb'))
read = [(float(x),float(y)) for (x,y) in reader]
dict_read = dict(read)
```

which loads the data in the desired way.

So, is it possible to modify the first `dict_read = dict((x,y) for (x,y) in reader)` to do what the code below does?

**SOLUTION:**
The solution is to use the map-function, which has to be used on iterable objects:

```
dict_read = dict(map(float,x) for x in reader)
```

Comment: Is it possible to get a comment from the down vote? Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dict_read = dict((map(float,x) for x in reader)
```

Comment: That solution didn't work directly, but pointed me to the map-function. I don't know, why I didn't discover this function through google.
The solution to my problem is:
`dict_read = dict(map(float,x) for x in reader)`
Since map as far as I can see only support iterable objects it returns an error for e.g. `map(float,'0.1')`, but the wanted behaviour for `map(float,('0.1','0.2'))`.
Anyway, thank you for pointing me to the map-function.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I intended to show you the way, admit it that I hadn't tested it.